# What is the maximum number of specials that can be alive at a time?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

First-person shooter co-op games usually limit the number of special units that can be alive at the same time, to avoid overwhelming the players with units that can easily wipe the team. For example, *Left 4 Dead 2* has a [console command](https://left4dead.fandom.com/wiki/Complete_list_of_console_commands/Z), `z_minion_limit` (default: 3), that sets the maximum number of “special infected” zombies that can be alive at any given time. This number is 3 by default to give at least one player on the team a fighting chance.

I want to know what this value is for *Vermintide 2*. How many specials can be alive at any given time? (Where beyond that maximum, the AI director will no longer spawn specials.) Is there a limit for the same special-unit type, or for disablers, specifically?

Please mention any differences between the difficulties (especially Legend and Cataclysm), between the game modes (Campaign and Chaos Wastes), and if the “Seek and Destroy” deed modifier is applied (described as: “specials spawn with much higher frequency and in larger numbers”).

##### In *Vermintide 2*, what is the maximum number of specials that can be alive at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Vermintide 2*'s [`conflict_settings.lua`](https://github.com/Aussiemon/Vermintide-2-Source-Code/blob/master/scripts/settings/conflict_settings.lua), a file containing all the difficulty settings, we can see, under the header `SpecialDifficultyOverrides` [r. 637], the values for `max_specials`. These vary by difficulty.

In this file, the difficulties are named `hard`, `harder`, `hardest`, `cataclysm`, `cataclysm_2`, and `cataclysm_3`.

We can see how they correspond with the difficulty levels in-game from this table in the adjacent [`difficulty_settings.lua`](https://github.com/Aussiemon/Vermintide-2-Source-Code/blob/master/scripts/settings/difficulty_settings.lua) file [r. 367]:

```
DifficultyMapping = {
  hardest = "legend",
  hard = "veteran",
  harder = "champion",
  cataclysm = "cataclysm",
  normal = "recruit"
}
```

So `max-specials` in `SpecialDifficultyOverrides` only sets the maximum for difficulty levels for *Veteran* and higher, reaching, as suggested by galacticninja, two difficulty levels that can be (customized and) used in [Weaves](https://vermintide2.fandom.com/wiki/Weaves), from the Winds of Magic DLC.<sup>*</sup>

Since *Recruit* is missing from the `SpecialDifficultyOverrides` class (not being a "special" difficulty, which makes sense), it must have a default value.

- I *think* this default value is `2` for *Recruit*,<sup>†</sup> but it could be `3`, as well.

The values for `max_specials` in `SpecialDifficultyOverrides` are:

- `3` for `Hard`/*Veteran* and `Harder`/*Champion*;
- `4` for `Hardest`/*Legend*;
- `5` for `Cataclysm`/*Cataclysm*;
- `6` for `cataclysm_2` and `cataclysm_3`.

From the file it is also clear that the types of specials to be spawned don't change with difficulty, but the amount of specials of the same type does change slightly: from Legend difficulty onwards, `max_of_same` changes from `2` to `3`.

Further down in the .lua file, there are some variations on this, called `SpecialDifficultyOverrides_` followed by, among others, `skaven`, `beastmen`, `chaos` and combinations thereof, but they generally follow the same pattern (safe for the first difficulty sometimes receiving a `max_specials` value of `2` rather than `3`).
The names refer to factions, but I'm not sure how these specific variables come into play: they *might* refer to specific maps. I'll look into that a little more.

---

* Somewhat corroborated by a table mentioned before the `DifficultyMapping` class in `difficulty_settings.lua`, called `DefaultDifficulties`, which doesn't mention `cataclysm_2` and `cataclysm_3`.

† Mainly because, as mentioned later in this answer, there are variations on this table based on factions, that have their maximum lowered from the `SpecialDifficultyOverrides`'s lowest `3` to `2`.
The file [`enemy_package_loader_settings.lua`](https://github.com/Aussiemon/Vermintide-2-Source-Code/blob/master/scripts/settings/enemy_package_loader_settings.lua) points to a `limit` of `3` specials [r. 132], but the conditions (and the fact they are there to begin with) make this being the default seem improbable.

Comment: I believe "hardest" = Legend, "cataclysm" = Cataclysm, and "normal" = Recruit, but I'm not sure why "normal" is not in the .lua file. I believe "cataclysm_2" and "cataclysm_3" are used in the Weaves game mode on the higher rank weaves, and are used by mods to introduce custom difficulties.

Comment: @galacticninja Ah, that could very well be! I haven't tried all features of the game since I only played it alone, which became a little boring after going through the main campaign twice..

Comment: @galacticninja I was about to edit in your information, but will look into the missing 'normal' setting. Maybe the default difficulty has standard, non-deviating values, that are mentioned somewhere else. (The values 'easy' and 'normal' are being used in other contexts in the same file.)

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning Fortunes of War's cataclysm. I remember it spawned 6 specials, but maybe I'm misremembering